# Convert JSON into XML using Java

Tags: java, json, xml

I'm trying to convert JSON into XML. But I'm getting an error that org.json cannot be resolved. I have also imported the external jar file java-json.jar. Below is my java code:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class JsontoXML{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    String str ={'name':'JSON','integer':1,'double':2.0,'boolean':true,'nested' {'id':42},'array':[1,2,3]}"; 
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
    String xml = XML.toString(json);
    System.out.println(xml);

  }
```

}

Comment: Well for starters you are missing an opening _"_  when you define your string, unless that is just a typo here

Comment: There is a problem with your `json` String. Put one more Closing Curlibraces at last of your String.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap thanks. I unzipped the jar file java-json jar and then used New External Jar and it worked.

Comment: @GordonAllocman thanks

Comment: use build tools like maven/gradle to build your project.

Comment: Have you added the jar to the build path of the application

Comment: @abhaybhatia Yes. Thanks.

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.jsonToXml(json).

Answer (score 5):

Your application is alright. You need to have a well formed JSON object.

**Source Code**

```
package algorithms;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
public class JsonToXML{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{name: JSON, integer: 1, double: 2.0, boolean: true, nested: { id: 42 }, array: [1, 2, 3]}");

    String xml = XML.toString(json);
    System.out.println(xml);

  }
}
```

Check with the example above.

**Output:**

```
<boolean>true</boolean><array>1</array><array>2</array><array>3</array><double>2.0</double><name>JSON</name><integer>1</integer><nested><id>42</id></nested>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Actually the problem was adding in the external jar file. I added the zip file. I unzipped the external jar file and now it's working.

Comment: but i am not getting the output in correct format....
Response generated: <nested><id>42</id></nested><integer>1</integer><name>JSON</name><boolean>true</boolean><double>2.0</double><array>1</array><array>2</array><array>3</array>

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to jar. You need to import the org.json package for the XML methods to work.

if you are using maven try:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20140107</version>
</dependency>
```

Or else download the jar from [this maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107) and add to your library.

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) can convert json to xml:

```
String json = "{\"name\":\"JSON\",\"integer\":1,\"double\":2.0,\"boolean\":true,\"nested\": {\"id\":42},"
    + "\"array\":[1,2,3]}";
String xml = U.jsonToXml(json);
System.out.println(xml);
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <name>JSON</name>
  <integer number="true">1</integer>
  <double number="true">2.0</double>
  <boolean boolean="true">true</boolean>
  <nested>
    <id number="true">42</id>
  </nested>
  <array number="true">1</array>
  <array number="true">2</array>
  <array number="true">3</array>
</root>
```